# SQL Server - check if sets of time ranges overlap each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, overlap

I have two tables with time ranges, Weeks and Periods:
Weeks:

```
WeekID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
1      | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-07 |
2      | 2017-01-08 | 2017-01-14 |
3      | 2017-01-15 | 2017-01-21 |
```

and Periods:

```
PeriodID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
1        | 2016-12-01 | 2017-01-03 |
2        | 2017-01-20 | 2017-02-28 |
3        | 2017-03-15 | 2017-03-16 |
```

I need to have only those records in table Weeks, that have some common dates with date ranges from Periods table. In other words, I need to delete from Weeks where time between StartDate and EndDate does not have any date in common with any of the time periods from periods table. Any thoughts how to do that?

The result Weeks table should be:

```
WeekID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
1      | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-07 |
3      | 2017-01-15 | 2017-01-21 |
```

Any thoughts on this will help.

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just writing a SP using '@Weeks' and '@Periods' tables.

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postrgres etc?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return `Weeks` that do not overlap a `Period`:

```
select *
from Weeks w
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Weeks l
      inner join Periods r
        on l.EndDate >= r.StartDate
       and r.EndDate >= l.StartDate
    where w.WeekId = l.WeekId 
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VYTEC19325

returns:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| WeekId | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      2 | 2017-01-08 | 2017-01-14 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

To delete those `Weeks`, change `select *` to `delete`.

To just select `Weeks` that overlap `Periods` change `not exists()` to `exists()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this.